# Convergence of Infinite Series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n-1}}{n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, radicals

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n-1}}{n} $$

According to Mathematica, this series converges. I can't figure out how to prove this, however. If I split the series apart, I get two divergent series. The ratio test comes out to 1, which is inconclusive. Additionally, every series I can think of comparing this to is divergent (like 1/$\sqrt{n}$). Any ideas on how to prove that this converges?

Comment: Rationalise the numerator.

Comment: See also: [Convergence of two series, $\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n-1}}{n}$ and $\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{\ln(n!)}{n^a}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2178092).

Comment: See also: [Does the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty$ ${\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}\over n$ converge or diverge?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/350580) and [Prove series is convergent $\sum\limits_{n=2}^\infty \frac{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}{n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1186251)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: Multiply both the denominator and numerator by $\sqrt{n-1} + \sqrt{n+1}$.

Comment: Wow I can't believe I missed that. So simple, thanks